# keyNotFound in codableKey for json response

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Json response parsing into codable string for dis error KeyNotFound.
KeyNotFound when codable to wrapper class

```
    Unexpected error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], 
debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil)
 (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil)).
```

Response Data

```
{
    "msg": {
        "success": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "jobs": {
            "current_page": 1,
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 154,
                    "user": "UserName"}
]
}
}
}
```

Service Call

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            let jsonData = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!

            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let user = try jsonDecoder.decode(JobListModel.self, from: data)
                print("Hello \(user.msg )")
            } catch {
                print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ModelClass.

```
struct JobListModel: Codable {

    let msg: Msg
    let data: Data

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case msg = "msg"
        case data = "data"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        msg = try values.decode(Msg.self, forKey: .msg)
        data = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .data)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(msg, forKey: .msg)
        try container.encode(data, forKey: .data)
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your Model.

Comment: on paste response json into https://jsonmaster.github.io/# generate the model class.

Comment: Show your swift model `JobListModel `.

Comment: updated in question

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of your decoding model is incorrect. Use the model below:

```
struct JobListModel: Codable {
    let msg: Msg
    let data: JobListData
}

struct JobListData: Codable {
    let jobs: Jobs
}

struct Jobs: Codable {
    let currentPage: Int
    let data: [JobData]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currentPage = "current_page"
        case data
    }
}

struct JobData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let user: String
}

struct Msg: Codable {
    let success: [String]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

In you model, you're using `Data` as the type of `data` key in *JSON* response.

`Data` is a predefined type and that's the reason error is being thrown while parsing.

**Solution:**

You need to modify it to some custom type Eg. `JobListData`. So, your **`Codable`** models should be like,

```
struct JobListModel: Codable {
    let msg: Msg
    let data: JobListData
}

struct JobListData: Codable {
    let jobs: Jobs
}

struct Jobs: Codable {
    let currentPage: Int
    let data: [JobsData]
}

struct JobsData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let user: String
}

struct Msg: Codable {
    let success: [String]
}
```

You can now parse the `data` like so,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(JobListModel.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In the above code I've used `convertFromSnakeCase` as the `decoder's` `keyDecodingStrategy`. With this you can avoid explicitly defining the `enum CodingKeys` just for handling the *snake-case keys* in the json response.

**Note:** Don't write the definitions for `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` explicitly when there is nothing specific to parse. Straightforward  parsing in `Codable` will be handled by the compiler automatically given that you design the model right.